# Convert from img to geotiff

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff

Using gdal translate, would it be possible to convert from IMG to GeoTIFF?

We have very little experience with gdal.

Answer (score 13):

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff  C:\temp\input\a.img   C:\temp\output\a.tif
```

and the batch option

[GDAL_translate: converting ESRI GRID to Geotiff in batch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54819/gdal-translate-converting-esri-grid-to-geotiff-in-batch)

'-of GTiff' this part is probably not even required as this is the default but will do no harm.

Answer (score 5):

As part of their [NED data delivery changes](http://nationalmap.gov/data_delivery/ned.html) in 2013, the National Map provided a set of file conversion scripts. See this script:

```
GDAL_IMG_2_GeoTIFF.bat c:\temp\input.img
```

The result is dropped in a sub-directory:

```
IMG_Output\GDAL_IMG_2_GeoTIFF.tif
```

For converting many files, you may consider this script

```
GDAL_Convert_All_IMG_2_GeoTIFF.bat
```

> Recursively Scans directory for IMG files and runs
> GDAL_IMG_2_GeoTIFF on all

> The GeoTIFF will be put in the same directory as
> the IMG file.

At the time of writing, the scripts are available as a zip file at [this link](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prd-tnm/RasterConversionScripts/USGS_Raster_Conversion_Scripts.zip).

Additional information about the USGS raster conversion scripts can be found at [this link](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/tools/rasterconversion/)