# How to load Erdas .img files into Whitebox?

Tags: erdas-imagine, whitebox-gat

Just installed Whitebox 3.2.3 and I'd like to import a 14 MB.img file.

The data import options do not list .img as a file source.

A web search has also turned up nothing.

Comment: Alternative to @PROBERT's suggestion ...why not just use another software (QGIS, GDAL, etc.) to convert your .img to a raster format Whitebox _does_ understand? For example, [you could use `gdal_translate` to convert your .img to a .tiff](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103833/4968).

Comment: @elrobis  it depends on the open-source software. Not always if you use another software sometimes it doesn't work very well. it is not like a powerful such as ArcGIS or ERDAS. You will have to figure it out. I'm just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

Their website is http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml

Look at the toolbox here that says Data Import or Conversion Tools

https://whiteboxgeospatial.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/wgat3_2_2_ss1.png

You could try that. I have not tried or downloaded the software myself. You need to play it around or check the HELP on their software.