# Batch Envi read and write to tif

Tags: geotiff-tiff, batch, envi

Is there a way to batch read in ENVI standard image files (they have associated headers) and export them to a GeoTiff ?

I have a folder of ~500 images

Comment: you could do it with GDAL (gdal_translate). Is it a solution for you ?

Answer (score 1):

GDAL solution. This is the base code.

> gdal_translate -of GTiff input.envi output.tif

Here is the stack exchange answer to do all files in a folder.

[loop GDAL translate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54819/gdal-translate-converting-esri-grid-to-geotiff-in-batch)

and here is the stack overflow solution.

[loop gdal translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691943/how-to-loop-through-several-files-using-gdal-and-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

This function 'ENVI_OUTPUT_TO_EXTERNAL_FORMAT' can solve your work if you have the license.
The help can be found in http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVI_OUTPUT_TO_EXTERNAL_FORMAT.html