# Saving VRT as raster?

Tags: raster, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I have made a VRT out of a few different single band rasters. I've played around with it in QGIS and it's great and I can do a save as and it'll become a real raster. To do further processing in the pipeline, the files need to be tif files, not a VRT.

How can I batch convert VRTs to real rasters?

Ideally It'd be using command line gdal utilities but I can do it in python too if that's easier.

Or conversely, is there any easier way to just stack rasters (with potentially non-overlapping cell sizes)?

Comment: If you're looking for command line syntax to batch process files, you need to specify what command line environment you are using, Windows CMD, Powershell, Linux/OSX BASH etc... If you are after batch syntax, then your question is probably a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/54819/2856

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform the conversion to GeoTIFF:

```
gdal_translate in.vrt out.tif
```

See the `gdal_translate` [help](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) and the GeoTIFF driver [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) for various other arguments and config options to control the conversion, such as whether to compress the output.

For stacking, look at [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html).

Something like:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate stacked.vrt [in vrts or rasters]
gdal_translate stacked.vrt stacked.tif
```

Note: this requires a **raster** VRT input. If you try to use a vector VRT you will get an error:

> `ERROR 4: 'in.vrt' not recognized as a supported file format.`

Vector VRTs need to be [rasterized](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/302162/2856).