# Opening vrt file?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, gdal

I would like to convert a `vrt` file into a raster dataset using `gdal_translate`. I am doing the following:

`gdal_translate in.vrt out.tif`

However I get the following error:

`ERROR 4: 'in_vrt' not recognized as a supported file format.

I have checked and rechecked my file name and path and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried opening in Arcmap and got this error message:

> Invalid raster dataset. Failed to create raster layer

and in QGIS I got:

> Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset in.vrt: `in.vrt'
>   not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is
>   not valid (provider: gdal, URI: in.vrt

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? How can I open this vrt file with no errors?

**EDIT**
Here are a few lines from a typical vrt I am using

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="gouda_rws_env_dsc_v3_ds_qh">
            <SrcDataSource>gouda_rws_env_dsc_v3_ds_qh.csv</SrcDataSource>
            <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
            <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
            <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="pnt_lon" y="pnt_lat"/>
            <Field name="pnt_id" src="pnt_id" type="String" />
            <Field name="pnt_lat" src="pnt_lat" type="Real" />
            <Field name="pnt_lon" src="pnt_lon" type="Real" />
            <Field name="pnt_rdx" src="pnt_rdx" type="Real" />
            <Field name="pnt_rdy" src="pnt_rdy" type="Real" />
            <Field name="pnt_demheight" src="pnt_demheight" type="Real" />
            <Field name="pnt_height" src="pnt_height" type="Real" />
```

Comment: check for mispells. is it in_vrt or in.vrt? Open the file into a text editor. Does it look like an xml file?

Comment: No I am not mispelling it. It is indeed an xml file but I do notice there are multiple fields. Do I somehow have to define these in the `gdal_translate` command?

Comment: IIRC, in some instances QGIS wants the filetype in the name of the VRT file. e.g. a VRT of GeoTIFFs named `Some raster map.vrt` might fail while the same VRT file named `Some raster map.tif.vrt` would work.  I could be well be mis-remembering though.

Comment: But my file is called "in.vrt" according to the file explorer

Comment: If the file you showed a sample of is one of the ones that's failing then try renaming the VRT file from "in.vrt" to "in.csv.vrt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VRT is a vector dataset.  `gdal_translate` is used to convert between raster formats not from vector to raster.

Instead, you can use:

- [`ogr2ogr`](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to output a shapefile or other vector format,

  - QGIS Processing toolbox | GDAL | Vector Conversion | Convert format
- [`gdal_rasterize`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) to burn the points to a tiff, or

  - QGIS Processing toolbox | GDAL | Vector Conversion | Rasterize
- [`gdal_grid`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) to interpolate the points to a surface raster (I noticed some elevation fields in your VRT).

  - QGIS Processing toolbox | GDAL | Raster Analysis | Grid (*)

If the underlying CSV file is meant to be a raster dataset in [XYZ format](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html), gdal/QGIS should be able to read it directly as a raster if you drop the additional fields and just keep the "pnt_lon", "pnt_lat" and "pnt_height" (OR "pnt_demheight" but not both), sorted by lat then by lon.  You could then use `gdal_translate xyz.csv out.tif`

> GDAL supports reading and writing ASCII gridded XYZ raster datasets (i.e. ungridded XYZ, LIDAR XYZ etc. must be opened by other means. See the documentation of the gdal_grid utility).
>
> Those datasets are ASCII files with (at least) 3 columns, each line
>   containing the X and Y coordinates of the center of the cell and the
>   value of the cell.
>
> The spacing between each cell must be constant and no missing value is
>   supported. Cells with same Y coordinates must be placed on consecutive
>   lines. For a same Y coordinate value, the lines in the dataset must be
>   organized by increasing X values. The value of the Y coordinate can
>   increase or decrease however. The supported column separators are
>   space, comma, semicolon and tabulations.
>
> The driver tries to autodetect an header line and will look for 'x',
>   'lon' or 'east' names to detect the index of the X column, 'y', 'lat'
>   or 'north' for the Y column and 'z', 'alt' or 'height' for the Z
>   column. If no header is present or one of the column could not be
>   identified in the header, the X, Y and Z columns (in that order) are
>   assumed to be the first 3 columns of each line.