# Batch convert .img to GeoTIFF using gdal_translate on Mac

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I want to convert all the .img in a folder and subfolfers to GeoTIFFs.

I do this regularly with gdal_translate for a single file:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff input.img output.tif
```

I'm trying to find out how to run this on the Mac terminal for all the files in a folder/subfolders.

(I have found options for Windows and Linux but not Mac e.g.:
[GDAL_translate: converting ESRI GRID to Geotiff in batch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54819/gdal-translate-converting-esri-grid-to-geotiff-in-batch))

Comment: Linux answers are applicable to MacOS. `find . -name '*.img' -exec zsh -c 'gdal_translate $0 $0:r.tif' {} \; `

Comment: This is not really a GIS question.  It's a shell scripting (or other OS-based automation) question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by user2856 in the comments worked. Navigate to folder then:

```
find . -name '*.img' -exec zsh -c 'gdal_translate $0 $0:r.tif' {} \;
```